# How do I recursively list all files of type *.mp3 in a Windows .bat file?

Tags: windows, directory, batch-file

I want to recursively list the absolute path to all files that end with `mp3` from a given directory which should be given as relative directory.

I would then like to strip also the directory from the file and I have read that variables which are in a `for`-scope must be enclosed in `!`s. Is that right?

My current code looks like this:

```
for /r %%x in (*.mp3) do (
    set di=%%x
    echo directory !di!
    C:\bla.exe  %%x !di!
)
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use the command `DIR`:

```
dir /s/b *.mp3
```

The above command will search the current path and all of its children. To get more information on how to use this command, open a command window and type `DIR /?`.

Comment: This works with explicit directory, too: `dir /s/b "c:\My music\*.mp3"`.

Answer (score 9):

The batch file below demonstrates how to extract elements of a filename from the variable in a `for` loop. Save this as file `listfiles.bat`, and run "listfiles some\folder *.mp3".

I set up the file finding as a subroutine in the batch file so you can insert it into your own scripts.

You can also run "for /?" in a cmd shell for more information on the `for` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
call :find-files %1 %2
echo PATHS: %PATHS%
echo NAMES: %NAMES%
goto :eof

:find-files
    set PATHS=
    set NAMES=
    for /r "%~1" %%P in ("%~2") do (
        set PATHS=!PATHS! "%%~fP"
        set NAMES=!NAMES! "%%~nP%%~xP"
    )
goto :eof
```